# excel formula using array of non adjacent cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with 2 columns, where

- `A` contains objects, and
- `B` their costs

I am trying to display the object that corresponds to the minimum cost of a range of non-adjacent cells. I wrote this formula:

```
  =INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},A3,A9,A12,A13,A18,A21,A22),MATCH(MIN(B3,B9,B12,B13,B18,B21,B22),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},B3,B9,B12,B13,B18,B21,B22),0))))
```

I get `#VALUE!`,  what's the error in my approach?

Comment: So, basically, all you want is get the name of the object whose corresponding value in B is the minimum among those cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just the `INDEX/MATCH` part

`=INDEX(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},A3,A9,A12,A13,A18,A21,A22),MATCH(MIN(B3,B9,B12,B13,B18,B21,B22),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},B3,B9,B12,B13,B18,B21,B22),0))`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you just want to get the name of the object whose value is the minimum among the cells you detailed.

```
=INDEX(A:B,MATCH(MIN(B3,B9,B12,B13,B18,B21,B22),B:B),1)
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: I don't think this will work reliably - what happens if you change B9 to 8? I get #N/A in that case......and also values in the intermediate cells can affect the calculation